# Android adMob not showing Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

**Activity XML**

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
     android:id="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     ads:adSize="BANNER"
     ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">
 </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**Activity Code**

```
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

 @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.resume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

**Build Grandle Code(Module App)**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
}
```

when i run it on my device the ad banner not showing,just a blank space
and it show E/Ads: JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined (:1) and E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY).

Whats the problem?

Comment: Check my answer and try it. If you have any issue then tell me

Comment: after some times add showing. wait some time or day.

Comment: have i first publish my app in google playstore?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code in my project and it is working fine. so you can make changes according to your project requirements. I hope it will be work for you. You can make changes banner ad unit code.

**Activity XML Code**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adView4"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**Activity Code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AdView mAdView5 = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView5);
            AdRequest adRequest5 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView5.loadAd(adRequest5);
}
```

**Build.Grandle(Module App) Code**

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.amazon.android:mobile-ads:5.+'
}
```

**strings.xml Code**

```
 <string name="banner_ad_unit_5">ca-app-pub-############/#########</string>
```

Comment: i cant use compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0' it show Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0. Then i use the 9.0.0 its not error but when i run it the ad banner not showing

Comment: hey i have figure my problem using firebase libary... and i want to ask since i use test device in my code to test ad in my device,should i still use test device if i want to publish in playstore? thx